# UTF8 Coding in OpenCart

Tags: php, utf-8, opencart

In OpenCart Daniel includes a UTF8 helper file with various UTF8 functions.

Here is my question ...

What is the resulting difference (I can't find any) in wrapping utf8 decoded code segments in native php functions vs. using the utf8 helper functions in OpenCart?

For example in OpenCart validation areas we see a lot of this:

```
if (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['myvalue']) < 3)
```

Which is exactly the same as:

```
if (strlen(utf8_decode($this->request->post['myvalue'])) < 3)
```

There are additional helper functions in the file for `utf8_strtolower`, `utf8_strpos` etc.

Why not simply use:

```
strtolower (utf8_decode($myvariable))
```

Just curious as I'm building a new CMS framework based on the OpenCart MVC.

**EDIT:** Adding new `mb_` class.

Here is the new class for `mb_` functions, please check for any errors.

```
final class Tester {

    public function _strlen ($string) {
        return mb_strlen ($string, mb_detect_encoding($string));
    }

    public function _strpos ($string, $needle, $offset = false) {
        if (!$offset):
            $data = explode ($needle, $string, 2);
            if (count ($data) > 1):
                $offset = $this->_strlen ($data[0]);
            endif;
        endif;

        return mb_strpos ($string, $needle, $offset, mb_detect_encoding ($string));
    }

    public function _strrpos ($string, $needle, $offset = false) {
        if (!$offset):
            $data = explode ($needle, $string);
            if (count ($data) > 1):
                array_pop ($data);
                $string = join ($needle, $data);
                $offset = $this->_strlen ($string);
            endif;
        endif;

        return mb_strrpos ($string, $needle, $offset, mb_detect_encoding ($string));
    }

    public function _substr ($string, $start, $length = false) {
        if (!$length):
            $length = $this->_strlen ($string);
        endif;

        return mb_substr ($string, $start, $length, mb_detect_encoding ($string));
    }

    public function _strtolower ($string) {
        return mb_strtolower ($string, mb_detect_encoding ($string));
    }

    public function _strtoupper ($string) {
        return mb_strtoupper ($string, mb_detect_encoding ($string));
    }

    public function _array ($data, $exit = true) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r ($data);
        echo "</pre>";

        if ($exit):
            exit;
        endif;
    }
}
```

This also includes my array testing function that I previously had in the loader class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hugo pointed out, these helper functions are just wrappers for calling two-three different functions. Sometimes these functions looks directly like a whole `strpos` **reimplementation** for `UTF-8` encoded text...

To be honest I do not like those `utf8_strtolower`/`utf8_strtoupper` implementations, nor other `utf8_*` functions within the helper (I think I'm gonna throw up). And whenever I am implementing my own module or other modifications I am using `mbstring` functions:

```
mb_strtolower($string, 'UTF-8');
mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8');
```

They are the same as basic string functions but take additional (**optional**) encoding parameter. There are many *multibyte operations*, check the [documentation](http://php.net/mb_string). These can be used with any encoding and even You do not know the encoding, You could use them this way:

```
// here the encoding is get by calling mb_internal_encoding() function, 
//which may not be the same as the string encoding
mb_strtolower($string); 

// and here we let PHP to detect the real encoding of the string
mb_strtolower($string, mb_detect_encoding($string));

// but if we are sure it is in e.g., UTF-8
mb_strtolower($string, 'UTF-8');
```

The only requirement for these functions is to enable the PHP `mbstring` extension.

**Edit** due to the comment: So You are also using new approach thus also breaking the consistency :-) Unless this new class will take part in new versions of OC (and replace the helper class). :-)

Anyway, it would be much much better to create the class `YouNameIt` (I cannot think of the name...) that will use only `mbstring` functions, like this:

```
class YouNameIt {

    public function strlen($string) {
        return mb_strlen($string, mb_detect_encoding($string));
    }

    public function substr($string, $start, $length = false) {
        if(!$length)
            $length = $this->strlen($string);

        return mb_strlen($string, $start, $length, mb_detect_encoding($string));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then You would just use (Okay, let's name it `mbstring`):

```
$this->mbstring->strlen($the_string);
```

With UTF-8 classes we are pretty tied down to use UTF-8 encoding which is not necessary... I may decide I want to use `ISO-*` encoding or `Windows-1250` shall I be really mad. With UTF8 class/helper this would be hardly possible... What do You think?

Comment: Thanks shady ... I agree, the helper class seems silly to me overall, but I suppose it has it's place.  My biggest issue is that I'm really anal about code style.  And while Daniel has done a pretty good job of keeping the code style clean and consistent, many of the modules you pick up don't.  Some will use the helper, and some use the `strlen(utf8_decode())` that I mentioned.  What I've done is create a new utf8 class and recoded the original helper so I can now search and replace `utf8_strlen()` with `$this->utf8->strlen()` and get a more consistent code base.

Comment: I think that's a great approach, although there are several other functions in the helper that need to be re-written as well. And yes, this breaks the consistency with OC, but as I said I'm creating a CMS with this MVC framework, and I've created a fork of OC with a great deal of consistency :) I'd love to use this approach, any ideas for re-writing the `strpos()` and `strrpos()` functions?

Comment: @VinceKronlein If You'd look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php), You'd find there are also [`mb_strpos`](http://php.net/mb_strpos) and [`mb_strrpos`](http://php.net/mb_strrpos) functions ;-) Is this CMS available somewhere (GitHub)? I was thinking of using OC for CMS too, I've started already, but stopped due to no time...

Comment: Beautiful ... love that! I'm all over it bro, will write that new class right now.  No it's not available just yet, but I'll give you a copy of it once it's done no problem. The basic coding is all complete for the most part, but I'm adding fully responsive templates for the front and back and like you, I don't have a huge amount of free time to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it doesnt realy matter. But as with all functions its to make things easier. Instead of writing `strlen(utf8_decode())` its easier to write `utf8_strlen()`. Another benifit is that you are not tempted to 'forget' to use the `utf8_decode` function and simply use `strlen()`.

So its doesnt realy matter what you use technically, but if you know you (almost) always have to make a double function call, why not create a helper for it?

Comment: Well ideally I'd rather convert the helper to a class and call it more elegantly and consistently.